# Stop rounding when importing Google finance currency

Tags: currency, floating-accuracy, google-finance

I am importing currency from Google finance to Google spreadsheets (latest version). The number that is imported is rounded both in terms of what is displayed and the underlying number. Is there a way to get the actual underlying currency number to all necessary decimal places?

Answer (score 0):

Look at your menu bar and select:

```
Format > Number > More Formats > Custom Number Format
```

Answer (score 0):

I used the external lookup -
=ImportHTML("http://www.xe.com","table", 1)

in a unused part of the spreadsheet and then sourced the appropriate rate from the table contents. Will probably work with other currencies too - look at xe.com
Updates every minute which is fine for my purposes.

Answer (score 0):

```
=round((googlefinance("asx:"&B12,"marketcap")/googlefinance("asx:"&B12,"shares")),4)
```

Where:

- ASX (Australian Stock eXchange) can be replaced for TSE, etc or removed for NASDAQ
- B12 is the Ticker.

Comment: please add the appropriate code formatting so other people can more easily read it